# C# and local database (access)

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need to help with displaying the data from the `listbox` output to the labels.
In the `listbox` everything is loaded (I need to see `Firstname` and `LastName`) but it does not write anything on the labels - always an error.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE groupA='" + listBox1.Text + "' ORDER BY FirstName";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add(reader["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + reader["LastName"].ToString());
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + ex);
        }
    }
```

listBox3_SelectedINdexChanged

```
private void listBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                string query = "select * from Tab1 where FirstName=" + listBox2.Text + "";
                command.CommandText = query;
```

`OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                label6.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                label8.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                label10.Text = reader["GroupPolice"].ToString();
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + ex);
        }
    }`

Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZwck.png)

Comment: `always an error.`  Always tell us the error.

Comment: You have to use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors, which is what is probably causing your issues.  A label can only show one value, so a while-loop doesn't make sense.  Use `if (reader.Read())` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the second query to:

```
string query = "select * from [Tab1] where FirstName='" + listBox2.Text + "'";
```

And `while (reader.Read())` to:

```
 if (reader.Read())
```